# Bitcoin core API for address

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, client, api, block

I installed bitcoin core and now it is completely synced. I am not able to find REST Api for a particular address.
I want to run my server so can i am able to make an http request for REST API

Comment: bitcoin core doesn't have rest api, please elaborate your question what kind of API calls your require

Comment: Since bitcoin core 0.12 (or 0.11?!) there is a REST interface

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable REST by setting `rest=1` in your `bitcoin.conf` or startup bitcoind with `-rest=1` or bitcoin-qt with `-server=1 and -rest=1`.

You can access REST by curl (example):
`curl localhost:18332/rest/getutxos/checkmempool/b2cdfd7b89def827ff8af7cd9bff7627ff72e5e8b0f71210f92ea7a4000c5d75-0.json`

A simple documentation is available here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/REST-interface.md

**EDIT:**
There is no REST API for addresses. Bitcoin-Core does not have an per-address index.
If you enable `-txindex=1`, you can retrieve any transaction with `GET /rest/tx/<TX-HASH>.<bin|hex|json>` (otherwise only transactions in the mempool).